# IE9 localStorage inconsistent

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a website that uses 3 IE9 browser windows: worklist, viewer, details. I use localStorage to set context and send messages between windows. All windows use the same origin but different URI.

On startup the worklist is displayed. Selecting an object opens the viewer and details windows. Closing those windows and selecting any object opens new viewer and details windows; however differences in localStorage leads to errors in the viewer and details.

To confound things, closing the viewer and details windows and selecting any object (again) produces the desired results.

This "bouncing" action of success and fail repeats fairly consistently.

Here's an example parent window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Local Storage Home</title>
<script>
var logArea = null;
function init() {
    localStorage.clear();
    logArea = document.getElementById('logArea');
}
function logMsg(msg) {
    logArea.innerHTML = logArea.innerHTML + msg + '\n';
}

var otherWin = null;
var chkFn = function() {
    if (!otherWin.closed){
        setTimeout(chkFn, 100);
    }
    else {
        showValues();
    }
};

window.addEventListener("storage",function(ev) {
    logMsg("STORE: " + ev.key + ' = ' + (ev.newValue || ""));
});

function runTest1() {
    logMsg("---- STARTING TEST 1 ----");
    localStorage.testId = 1;

    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    otherWin = window.open('LSPopup.html?popName=my first test&popId=1&myVal='+rndNum);
    setTimeout(chkFn, 1000);
}
function runTest2() {
    logMsg("---- STARTING TEST 2 ----");
    localStorage.testId = 2;

    var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    otherWin = window.open('LSPopup.html?popName=my test 2&popId=2&testVal='+rndNum);
    setTimeout(chkFn, 1000);
}

function showValues() {
    logMsg("---- Local Storage");
    var lskeys=Object.keys(localStorage);
    var cnt, len = lskeys.length;

    for(cnt=0; cnt < len; cnt++) {
        logMsg(('0'+(cnt+1)).substr(-2) + ': ' + lskeys[cnt] + ' = ' + localStorage[lskeys[cnt]]);
    }
    logMsg('Avail: ' + localStorage.remainingSpace);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h2>Local Storage Test</h2><br>
<div style="width:100% border:1px solid #000; padding: 5px; background-color: #ddd;">Console</div>
<textarea id="logArea" style="width: 100%" rows="12"></textarea>
<button onclick="runTest1()">Start Test 1</button>
<button onclick="runTest2()">Start Test 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the popup window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Local Storage POPUP</title>
<script>
var logArea = null;

function init() {
    logArea = document.getElementById('logArea');

    var keyvalue = location.search.substr(1).split('&');

    keyvalue.forEach(function (pair) {
        var kv = pair.split('=');
        logMsg('Set ' + kv[0] + ' = ' + decodeURIComponent(kv[1]));
        localStorage[kv[0]] = decodeURIComponent(kv[1]);
    });
    logMsg("---- Existing Values ----");
    var lskeys=Object.keys(localStorage);
    var cnt, len = lskeys.length;

    for(cnt=0; cnt < len; cnt++) {
        logMsg(('0'+(cnt+1)).substr(-2) + ': ' + lskeys[cnt] + ' = ' + localStorage[lskeys[cnt]]);
    }
    logMsg('Avail: ' + localStorage.remainingSpace);
}

function finishTest() {
    window.close();
}

function logMsg(msg) {
    logArea.innerHTML = logArea.innerHTML + msg + '\n';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<h2>Local Storage POPUP</h2><br>
<div style="width:100% border:1px solid #000; padding: 5px; background-color: #ddd;">Console</div>
<textarea id="logArea" style="width: 100%" rows="12"></textarea>
<button onclick="finishTest()">Complete Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result of the test pages show storage events but localStorage changes on the popup never show up on the main window.